# Xcode 6.4 only shows only iPhone 6 simulator to run

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

i am running Xcode 6.4 and there is only a single iPhone 6 simulator available. how can i get the whole set of available devices back,

[image: XCode Simulator]

i have installed all available components.

[image: XCode Components]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the devices from the Xcode > Window > Devices

[image]

Add the device which you want to add by pressing + Sign on left bottom.

[image]

Comment: @MugunthanBalakrishnan Welcome anytime :)

Comment: @MugunthanBalakrishnan Didn't know. I hope the question is already asked in the stack overflow before. I am not sure.